# Why is it not the other way around? TST operator ARM 32bit assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, logical-operators

Here we have code: (I copied it from another question that asks a similar but not the same question)

```
mov R0, #167
TST R0, #1
addeq ... //add if even
addne ... //add if not even
```

I wonder why is it not addeq if it's NOT even. My thinking is that TST tests the LSB (right most, least significant bit) of the number 167 which is 1 and the LSB of number 1 which is 1. Since they're the same why do I have to do addne rather than addeq because my thinking is that those two bits are both 1 so they're equal. But here when it's eq then it means that they're different.

Thanks for reading. I've read the documentation, I still can't understand this.

Comment: The `EQ` condition code asks if the Z (zero) flag is set, i.e. if the result of the last flag-setting instuction was zero.  This is the case when two numbers compare equal for example.

Comment: `TST` sets the flags based on the result of `operand1 AND operand2`, i.e. `167 & 1` in this case (which equals 1). Since the result is non-zero, the `Z` flag will be cleared, which means that the `NE` condition is true and the `EQ` condition is false.

Comment: `tst` is nothing else than `and` without a destination; The condition code `eq` means "equal zero".

Comment: what part of the documentation do you not understand?  please post the relevant text

Comment: It's true that the `EQ` mnemonic is not very intuitive in this situation.  x86 lets you use `Z/NZ` as synonyms for this reason, but ARM assemblers don't seem to allow that.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov R0, #167
```

R0=0xA7

```
TST R0, #1
```

alu=0xA7 & 1 = 1
if result = 0 Z(ero) flag = 1
so Z flag is 0

```
addeq ... //add if even
```

If Z flag == 1 then

```
addne ... //add if not even
```

If Z flag == 0 then

If it helps, if the lsbit is equal to 0 then it is even, so addeq, eq, means equal to zero, so it is even.  If the lsbit is 1 then it is odd, so addne, ne, not equal to zero, means odd.

If you want to know if the result of the alu operation is a zero then you use eq, equal to zero as your conditional.  If you want to know if the result of the operation is not-zero you use ne, not equal to zero.

Even numbers the lsbit is a 0.  Odd numbers the lsbit is a 1.

```
0000 EQ Equal Z set 
0001 NE Not equal Z clear
```

...

```
Operation
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
alu_out = Rn AND shifter_operand
N Flag = alu_out[31]
Z Flag = if alu_out == 0 then 1 else 0
C Flag = shifter_carry_out
V Flag = unaffected
```

The documentation seems quite clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to concentrate on one aspect of your question:

> ... so they're **equal**.

You are confused because `EQ` indeed means "equal":

However, the names of the conditions (`EQ` = equal, `GT` = greater-than, `LE` = less-or-equal) typically refer to a previous `CMP x,y` instruction:

An `...EQ` instruction is executed after a `CMP x,y` instruction if `x` and `y` are equal.

However, in your case, the instruction setting the flags (`N`, `V`, `C`, `Z`) is not `CMP`, but by `TST`.

Because of this, you cannot refer to the English language meanings of the conditions (such as "`EQ` = equal").

This is not only true for ARM CPUs, but for most CPU types:

If the flags are not set by `CMP` (but by `TST`, `ADD` ...), you cannot refer to the English meaning of the condition.

Comment: The semantic meaning of the EQ / NE conditions after `tst` match `a & b == 0`.  (Just like after cmp, they match `a - b == 0`, which happens to be the same thing as `a == b`).  Similarly, MI / PL (minus = negative,  plus = non-negative) conditions indicate that `a & b >= 0` or not, i.e. value of the MSB.  So you *can* use some of the English meanings once you reinterpret them as a compare-with-zero of the AND result.